# How to get textbox values from a particular row where user is entering value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding data to html table dynamically on a button click using loadbooks function. When user clicks on this button, the table is filled with data dynamically.

```
<button id="button" onclick="loadbooks()"></button> function loadbooks() { ... ... for(var j in indivudvalbookdetails) { // if(indivudvalbookdetails[j]['barcode'] !="") //{ count++; $('.library_info_tbl tbody').append('
<tr>' + '
  <td class="text-center centeralign"> ' + data[i]['callno'] + '</td>' + '
  <td class="text-center centeralign"> ' + data[i]['subject'] + '</td>' + '
  <td class="text-center centeralign"> ' + data[i]['title'] + ' </td>' + '
  <td class="text-center centeralign"> ' + data[i]['isbn'] + '</td>' + '
  <td class="text-center centeralign"> ' + data[i]['author'] + ' </td>' + '
  <td class="text-center centeralign"> ' + indivudvalbookdetails[j]['acquisitionno'] + '</td>' + '
  <td class="text-center centeralign">
    <div class="btn-group">' + '
      <input type="text" id="barcodedb'+id+'" value="'+indivudvalbookdetails[j]['barcode']+'" class="form-control hide">'+ '
      <input type="text" id="barcode'+id+'" value="'+indivudvalbookdetails[j]['barcode']+'" class="form-control barcode">'+ '
      <p id="barcodeerror'+id+'" style="color:red; display:none;">Already Assigned</p>'+ '
    </div>
  </td>' + '
</tr>'); id++; // } } ... }
```

I am showing how one row is rendered in browser

```
<tr><td class="text-center centeralign"> 14</td><td class="text-center centeralign"> Communication</td><td class="text-center centeralign"> Nueral Network </td><td class="text-center centeralign"> 6578975667</td><td class="text-center centeralign"> kggfiuigfuit </td><td class="text-center centeralign"> 54</td><td class="text-center centeralign"><div class="btn-group"><input type="text" id="barcodedb0" value="jkyifujyirkruf" class="form-control hide"><input type="text" id="barcode0" value="jkyifujyirkruf" class="form-control barcode"><p id="barcodeerror0" style="color:red; display:none;">Already Assigned</p></div></td></tr>
```

Similary there are many other rows rendered in the browser.

Please note that there are two textboxes one gets hidden by class="hide"(used for comparision operation latter).

Now the user will enter something in one of the textbox with ids barcode0 or barcode1 etc.

Please have a look at below function which I am using for retrieving textbox value

```
$('#library_info_tbl tbody tr td').on("keyup", "input:nth-child(2)", function(j) {
  var barcode = $("#barcode" + j).val().trim();
  var barcodedb = $("#barcodedb" + j).val().trim();
  $("#barcodeerror" + j).css("display", "block");

});
```

Basically I have perform comparisions and other thing on the textbox values on that textbox where user is entering or entered some value and that textbox is present in the row of the table.

The above jquery on change event of textbox is not getting triggered...

Comment: Are you binding event before the TDs are appended to the DOM? Because regarding your `change` event binding, `TDs` need to be static. At least, try: `$('#library_info_tbl tbody').on("change", "tr td input:nth-child(2)", function(j){...});`

Comment: When page is first loaded, the table is empty and there is only a button, when button is clicked then that table gets filled with data...

Comment: I have tried using "$('#library_info_tbl tbody').on("change", "tr td input:nth-child(2)", function(j){});"  It does not work... Please help me

Comment: If the table is empty, there is no `tbody` to start with. So try instead: `$('#library_info_tbl').on("change", "tbody tr td input:nth-child(2)", function(j){...});`

Comment: Oh sorry I mean by keyup event... I have updated my question.... when I debug the code in console the j is not getting the correct value so the rest of the code doesnot work...

Comment: j is getting values like "j = n.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keyup", isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, timeStamp: 316192.12000000005, jQuery211032157135038053464: true, …}"

Comment: j should contain current row index value. let us suppose when user is entering some value in textbox which is present in the third row then the line " var barcode = $("#barcode"+j)" should become  var barcode = $("#barcode3")...

Comment: R u getting my points... Please help!!!

Comment: `j` is the jq event object, not the index. To get the relevant value, just use: `var barcode = $(this).val().trim(); var barcodedb = $(this).prev().val().trim();`. BUT how is it related to your former question???  AND to get index (but why?!), you can use: `var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();`

Comment: I am sorry for not looking at that jquery line before posting question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find unique id for each row, You could give each row an id and then get the id using

```
  var thisRow =  $(this).closest('tr');

   var thisRowId = thisRow.attr('id');
```

Then you can write

```
var barcode = $("#barcode" + thisRowId).val().trim();
```